# Data grid scrollable

Tags: javascript, html, css, extjs4.1

Hi I want to paint data grid using extjs 4 framework and want to make that data table scrollable horizontally(advances one column at a time,see the snapshot)
[image: snapshot of data table with scroll bar functionality i seek to achieve]

Doesn't want normal scroll bar rather it should be like arrows.

Comment: ExtJS doesn't have something like this out of the box, you need to implement this yourself

Comment: `overflow: scroll;` attribute of CSS? http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp